# error in EXECUTE IMMEDIATE insert ORACLE

Tags: sql, oracle, execute-immediate

good night.
I have a problem with the EXECUTE IMMEDIATE in oracle.
I look in others topics, but no answer was helpful.
This is the code:
First, the table that i need insert inside of trigger...

```
create global temporary table TEMP_PK (COL_NAME VARCHAR(100), COL_TYPE VARCHAR(100), ROW_VALUE VARCHAR(100)) on commit preserve rows;
```

Now, my trigger

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER ICidade AFTER
  INSERT ON Cidade FOR EACH ROW DECLARE TYPE EmpCurTyp IS REF CURSOR;
  emp_cv EmpCurTyp;
  col_name_aux VARCHAR(100);
  col_type_aux VARCHAR(100);
  stm          VARCHAR(4000):='';
  BEGIN
    -- Pegando as PKS
    FOR j IN
    (SELECT d.Column_Name coluna,
        d.DATA_TYPE tipo
      FROM user_cons_columns ucc,
        user_constraints uc,
        (SELECT COLUMN_NAME,DATA_TYPE FROM ALL_TAB_COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME='CIDADE'
        ) d
      WHERE uc.constraint_name=ucc.constraint_name
      AND uc.constraint_type  ='P'
      AND uc.table_name       = 'CIDADE'
      AND d.COLUMN_NAME       =ucc.Column_Name
    )
    LOOP
      stm := concat
      (
        stm, 'INSERT INTO TEMP_PK VALUES ('
      )
      ;
      stm := concat(stm, j.coluna);
      stm := concat(stm,', ');
      stm := concat(stm, j.tipo);
      stm := concat(stm,', ');
      stm := concat(stm, ':NEW.');
      stm := concat(stm,j.coluna);
      stm := concat(stm,')');

      EXECUTE IMMEDIATE stm;
      stm:='';
    END LOOP;


  END ICidade;
  /
```

Is compiling good. The problem is when I add an entry in the table "Cidade"
When I try to insert, for example:

```
Insert into Cidade Values (11,'Alegre','ES');
```

When I run without the immediate execute, using the print function, this is the result:

> INSERT INTO TEMP_PK VALUES ( CODCIDADE, NUMBER, :NEW.CODCIDADE);

With the EXECUTE IMMEDIATE, gives the following error:

> Error starting at line : 62 in command - Insert into Cidade VAlues
>   (11,'Alegre','ES') Error report - SQL Error: ORA-00936: missing
>   expression ORA-06512: at "PAULA.ICIDADE", line 34 ORA-04088: error
>   during execution of trigger 'PAULA.ICIDADE'
>   00936. 00000 -  "missing expression"

Probably is an idiot error, but i can't find.

So can anyone help me? Since now, thank you.

Comment: If you pull the SELECT statement out of the trigger and run in in a query tool such as SQL*Plus does it give back the column names and values you expect?

Comment: Yes, normally inserts @bob-jarvis

Comment: Quite tricky if you have to fill TEMP_PK with dynamic INSERT. Usually the definition of a Primary Key does not change so many times, so a static INSERT may be sufficient. You should consider to write a dedicated INSERT-Procedure which does everything, instead of using a trigger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you need to put single-quotes around the string literals being inserted into the COL_NAME and COL_TYPE columns. Try rewriting the trigger as:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER ICidade AFTER
  INSERT ON Cidade FOR EACH ROW DECLARE TYPE EmpCurTyp IS REF CURSOR;
  emp_cv EmpCurTyp;
  col_name_aux VARCHAR(100);
  col_type_aux VARCHAR(100);
  stm          VARCHAR(4000):='';
  BEGIN
    -- Pegando as PKS
    FOR j IN
    (SELECT d.Column_Name coluna,
        d.DATA_TYPE tipo
      FROM user_cons_columns ucc,
        user_constraints uc,
        (SELECT COLUMN_NAME,DATA_TYPE FROM ALL_TAB_COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME='CIDADE'
        ) d
      WHERE uc.constraint_name=ucc.constraint_name
      AND uc.constraint_type  ='P'
      AND uc.table_name       = 'CIDADE'
      AND d.COLUMN_NAME       =ucc.Column_Name
    )
    LOOP
      stm := 'INSERT INTO TEMP_PK (COL_NAME, COL_TYPE, ROW_VALUE) ' ||
             'VALUES (''' || j.coluna || ''', ' ||
                      '''' || j.tipo || ''', ' ||
                      ':NEW.' || j.coluna || ')';

      EXECUTE IMMEDIATE stm;
    END LOOP;
  END ICidade;
```

Share and enjoy.

Comment: Thank you. This error solved rs 

 Another appeared * Sad *, gave "not all variables bound". But now I will try to solve. And again, thank you.

Comment: Problem is term like ':NEW' inside a trigger is used for the new value of column, but also used in dynamic SQL for bind-variables. I don't think there is any solution to use both inside a trigger.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you use DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE to output `stm` before you execute it.  This will make it easier to see what you are running and why you have generate the wrong SQL.

For a start, you are not binding anything to `:NEW`

Comment: So I've seen the output, was printing before. I just took to post here rs

My problem is with ':new', because I need to get the value of it in accordance with the table name, you have any idea how can I do this?